# Questions about ANOVA analysis in R of groups

Tags: r, anova

I'm doing ANOVA analysis on a dataset that looks like:

| ID | cluster | gender | description | country | age |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 124 | 1 | F | SMALL | US | 32 |
| 324 | 1 | M | MEDIUM | CA | 12 |
| 82 | 5 | F | SMALL | US | 45 |
| 453 | 2 | F | LARGE | AU | 34 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 473 | 3 | M | SMALL | DK | 32 |
| 172 | 4 | M | LARGE | US | 62 |
| 23 | 4 | F | LARGE | US | 23 |

This dataset is a summary of the data. My data is divided into 5 clusters, and I would like to see how all the other variables, except ID, are unique to each cluster. I was recommended to use an ANOVA analysis for this. I got some results, but they didn't quite line up with what I saw graphically. For example, I thought gender would be statistically significant given my bar graph visualization, but it's not. This is okay if true (obviously there is nothing I can do about it), but I wanted to check to be sure I was doing this correctly and to see if there is a different way to do this other than ANOVA.

here is what I have been doing:

```
one.way.gender <- aov(cluster ~ gender, data = data1)
summary(one.way.gender)

one.way.description <- aov(cluster ~ description, data = data1)
summary(one.way.description)

one.way.country <- aov(cluster ~ country, data = data1)
summary(one.way.country)

one.way.age <- aov(cluster ~ age, data = data1)
summary(one.way.age)
```

I know this is a very simple way of doing this, and I'm worried I'm missing something. I've went through a few tutorials with more lengthy code to the analysis, but they yield the same results as the simple code.

Comment: Sorry, is "cluster" a numeric, continuous variable? The way you describe it sounds like its a clustering (i.e. categorical) variable, in which case ANOVA is not appropriate. If it is numerical, I'm not quite sure about what you mean by "how other variables are unique to each cluster". With the analyses you have conducted, you get to know how means of "cluster" vary by levels of gender etc.

Comment: @sointu its continuous, which is why I'm a bit nervous about it, and I figured it wasn't appropriate. It was recommended on a previous thread where I was askin about this. Yes, I have raw counts of the demographics in each cluster. However, my cluster analysis wasn't based on these demographics, so now I'm looking for a way to meaningfully represent what I'm seeing, other than just a visual graph.

Comment: In my view you shouldn't have the cluster membership as the dependent variable in an ANOVA but I see you were recommended to use ANOVA by much more experienced users, so I'm going to bow out - hope you get an answer!

Comment: @sointu I accidentally posted the same question in regular stack overflow as well. I was recommended the chi squared test for my categorical variables and Kruskal Wallis for the non categorical. I had already seen this recommended in a text book, so this is the way I'm going. After reading, I agree ANOVA wasn't the way to go. I think I may not have explained my problem very well, which led to some confusion in the previous thread.

Comment: Yeah, I would use chi-squared test for the cluster membership-categorical variable relationships. If you have continuous covariates, you could use ANOVA or Kruskal-Wallis for those, but with cluster membership as the independent (predictor) and the continuous covariate as the dependent (regression with the continuous as dependent would probably also work).